# Scalar Curvature evaluation at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I have silly question about the evaluation of the Ricci scalar curvature at singularities.

Suppose $\theta=(x,m) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ a classic two-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ with diagonal metric,

$d\ell^{2}=g_{11}dx^{2}+g_{22}dm^{2}$,

where

$g_{11}=8x^{2}\quad and \quad g_{22}=2$.

The metric imposes a scalar curvature R written as follows,

$\mbox{R}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{g}}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial g_{22}}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial m}\right)\right]$.

Suppose we want  to evaluate R at $x(m)=\pm \sqrt{m}$.  Should I first calculate $g_{11}$ and $g_{22}$ at $x(m)=\pm \sqrt{m}$, and then substitute the given results into R? or should I calculate R, and then evaluate the final expression at  $x(m)=\pm \sqrt{m}$?

Comment: Of course you should compute the tensor in general and then evaluate. But the only singularity I see is along $x=0$, so you're trying to examine the curvature specifically at $x=\mu=0$ and not at general $(0,\mu)$? ... I also don't know why you're writing $x=\pm\sqrt\mu$, presuming that $\mu>0$, rather than looking at the curve $\mu = x^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question above since there is no $\mu$ at all. In the above, $x$ and $m$ play the order and control parameters, respectively. What would be the problem  If I first calculate $g_{11}$ and $g_{22}$ at $x(m)=\sqrt{m}$, and then substitute the given result at R?

Comment: My comments stand. I don't care whether you call $m$ $\mu$ or not :P

Comment: The aim is to evaluate R as a function of $m$, and then find instances of divergence.

Comment: OK, fine. Do the general calculation and substitute your curve afterwards. You can do the chain rule computation, but I don't see any virtue in that. By the way, for surfaces, there's just one curvature (Gauss) ... no need to talk about Ricci or scalar. They're all the same.

Comment: Thank you so much once again, and my apologies for any inconvenience. There are no many people in my department to talk about differential geometry.

Comment: No need to apologize :) Let us know how the computation goes.